# Loading test data from a CSV file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, browserify

I'm working on unit tests for an AngularJS application. I have a CSV file of test cases which I'd like to pull into a particular suite, but I'm not familiar enough with Jasmine, Karma, or Node in general to work out how to do that. I figure I need to install the [csv](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv) package, but once that's done it's not clear to me how to access it.

The instructions for the `csv` package use RequireJS, but I haven't seen examples of code that integrates RequireJS into angular-seed. [This page](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/plus/RequireJS.html) on Karma's site describes a completely different application structure/flow to angular-seed which I am using currently.

EDIT: Thanks to marfarma's answer I have installed `karma-browserify` and now have access to node.js-style `require` in my rest cases. However, the filesystem seems to be broken:

```
describe("MyController", function() {
    var fs = require('fs');
    console.log(fs, fs.readFile);
});
```

Will print:

```
LOG: Object{exists: undefined}, undefined
```

This is running using `PhantomJS` - is it simply the case that I won't be able to access the filesystem while writing tests to run in browsers?

Comment: "is it simply the case that I won't be able to access the filesystem while writing tests to run in browsers?" - yes

Comment: added work around to my answer

Comment: @marfarma Thanks! I'll try that method. I assume testing using `jasmine-node` would alleviate this, but I prefer `karma` so I will just have to bite the bullet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The csv package you've linked to uses node.js style requires.  [Browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) supports their use in the browser. Here are a few tutorials on Browserify & Angularjs:

- https://npmjs.org/package/karma-browserify
- http://dontkry.com/posts/code/angular-browserify-grunt.html
- http://ethanway.com/angular-and-browserify/

And, since you can't read directly from the filesystem from the browser, serve your csv file alongside your angular app, for example:

```
var request = require('request');
var done = false;

request("http://localhost:8080/data.csv", function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // body is the csv data -- parse and save for later use
  }
  done = true;
})

waitsFor(function() {
  return done;
}, "csv data fetch never completed.", 10000);

// use it

describe('it should work',function() {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've started to integrate `karma-browserify`, but it's creating some problems in my test suite. Does this plugin require that I `browserify` my regular application source files as well?

Comment: Specifically, my calls to `beforeEach(module('app'));` are failing with a `TypeError`, so only my unit tests for non-Angular utils are running.

Comment: Ok, I realised that `module` was defined by `browserify`, and its definition was shadowing the `module` function provided by the Angular mock testing code. I replaced my calls to `module` with `angular.mock.module` and everything is working! Thanks.

Comment: ...or not. See my edit. I think I might be going about this wrong.